I can't change "Default operating system used for deployment" to Custom/alma9 in MAAS
I wanna change "Default operating system used for deployment" in MAAS 3.5 to Custom/alma9 but when I try to do this I got an error:
Error: 'alma9' is not a valid release. It should be one of: 'noble'.



If this is about Canonical MAAS, it really hasn't anything to do with Ubuntu.
